# Filling a ListPlot with an optical spectrum

Tags: plotting, graphics, color, physics, filling

I have discrete optical spectra data consisting of pairs of wavelengths and intensities, and I would like to make a `ListPlot` in which the points are both *joined*, and colored according to the wavelength *as is the filling*.

[Here is an example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emission_spectrum).

Here's fake data that illustrates the problem:

```
ListPlot[
 Table[Style[{λ, Sin[λ/400]}, 
   ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][λ]],
   {λ, 400, 700, 5}], 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium],
 Filling -> Axis,
 FillingStyle -> Function[{λ, y}, ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][#[[1]] &]]]
```

I can get the points to be properly colored, but not the filling.  Moreover, the ideal is to have a *continuous* filling underneath curve (as in the linked example), i.e., not discrete bars.  I've tried numerous variations on the `FillingStyle`, without success.

[image]

Comment: You might want to use the color functions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73161) instead of `ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"]`.

Comment: But `VisibleSpectrum` takes the wavelength (in nanometers) and renders the color—just as is the form of my data.  Shouldn't there be an easy way to call VisibleSpectrum in FillingStyle?!

Comment: My point in making my earlier comment was that [`"VisibleSpectrum"` does not always give accurate colors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11480). It was only a suggestion; if you insist on using `"VisibleSpectrum"`, then sure, you can use it in `FillingStyle`: `ListLinePlot[Table[{x, Sin[x/400]}, {x, 400, 700, 5}], ColorFunction -> (ColorData["VisibleSpectrum", #] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Filling -> Axis]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
fcolor = ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"]; 
ListPlot[Table[{x, Sin[x/400]}, {x, 400, 700, 5}], Joined -> True, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, fcolor[x]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Comment: Almost.  I had found such a `ColorFunction` but 1) the color should be a function of the abscissa ($x$) value (not $y$ value) and 2) it should be colored according to `ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"]` (not `Hue`).  Any way to fix that in your code?  (I couldn't find it.)

Comment: Though now I see that JM in the comments has beat me to it...

Comment: @bill, I upvoted, don't fret. ;) I didn't answer because I was expecting you'd fix yours.

Comment: J.M.:  You deserve the "win."  Post and I'll accept it.  Otherwise, I'll go with bill s.  Regardless:  Thanks you two!

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to use `"VisibleSpectrum"` it can be supplied directly in [`Blend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blend.html):

```
ListLinePlot[
  Table[{x, Sin[x/400]}, {x, 400, 700, 5}]
  , ColorFunction -> (Blend["VisibleSpectrum", #] &)
  , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
  , Filling -> Axis
]
```

[image]

However I recommend that you *do not* use that [inaccurate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11480/121) function but instead:

```
ChromaticityPlot;  (* pre-load internals *)

newVisibleSpectrum =
  With[
    {colors =
      {Image`ColorOperationsDump`$wavelengths,
       XYZColor @@@ Image`ColorOperationsDump`tris}\[Transpose]},
    Blend[colors, #] &
  ];

ListLinePlot[
  Table[{x, Sin[x/400]}, {x, 400, 700, 5}]
  , ColorFunction -> newVisibleSpectrum
  , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
  , Filling -> Axis
]
```

[image]

See: [A better "VisibleSpectrum" function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73161/121)

Or with `newVSgray` also from there:

[image]

That provides the closest unclipped representation possible within sRGB.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html)

```
data = Table[{λ, Sin[λ/400]}, {λ, 400, 700, 5}];

f = Interpolation[data];

Plot[f[λ], {λ, 400, 700}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][x]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Automatic,
 Axes -> False,
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
    {"Wavelength (nm)", "Intensity"})]
```

[image]